# How to display binary data as image

Tags: javascript, c#

i have been trying to show binary data in image but things are not working as expected .

on server side (c#), i m sending my byte[] like this

```
context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
context.HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(ImageBytes);
context.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

on client side

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Main/RenderPDF',
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(serverObj),
    dataType: "binary",
    processData: false,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        '__RequestVerificationToken': '',
        '__RequestVerificationToken': $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, request) {

        var headers = ['docId', 'pageHeight', 'pageWidth', 'width', 'height', 'pageNumber'],
            response = {};
        _.forEach(headers, function (item) { response[item] = request.getResponseHeader(item) })
        response.imageBytes = hexToBase64(data);
        callBack(response);
    }
});

function hexToBase64(str) {
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, str.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1   ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" ")));
}
```

it breaks code on hexToBase64 and use plain bytes and append image like

```
 $img.attr('src', "data:image/png;base64," +response.imageBytes);
```

issue is this when i debug in vs i get something like

[image]

i dont know why its not working can some one help me what needs to be changed or fixed

any help will be appreciated 
Regards

Comment: You are calling `hexToBase64` but where do you convert the binary data to hex?  I'm assuming your server code sends back the plain bytes.

Comment: yes its send plain bytes i have posted c# code , but issue is when it hextoBase64 code run it breaks as there is null value in data :S